# pycuda on windows 7 x64 bit visual studio2010

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, cuda, nvidia, pycuda

i'd tried for more than week to trace down a clear/clean install of pycuda on my win7 x64bit machine and found http://wiki.tiker.net/PyCuda/Installation/Windows
which-i can surely say- the only page everyone keep ref to it and it's too vague.
i am asking for any one who really use pycuda can help me setup it on my machine ,using it with visual studio 2010,,and any guide on installation and pdf resourcess

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the VS 10 compiler. Pycuda does  not support  this compiler. Someone should update pycuda for that. I am also trying to find a workaround!

Answer (score 0):

I've installed pycuda on Windows 7 64bit a few of times using the instructions on that page. How easy the instructions are to follow will depend on your level of familiarity with, python, cuda, and C++.

IMO, if this is the first time you are installing most of the required apps, go with the all binary approach:

http://wiki.tiker.net/PyCuda/Installation/Windows#Windows_7_64-bit_with_Visual_Studio_Professional_2008_.28Strictly_Binary_Versions.29

Remove everything you have done so far and start from there.